# Azure Notification Hub Registered Device list

Tags: ios, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-notificationhub

I am following [This Post](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-aspnet-register-user-push-notifications/) to work with azure notification hub. What i am trying to do is creating the web api that registers the devices with the Azure notification hub. When i send the request for registering the device as shown in the article it hits the azure notification hub.

Below is the screen shot of my azure portal. Which shows there was a request for registration.

But when i try to get the details of the registered devices using the following code it is always 0.

```
var registrationsCount = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(Int32.MaxValue);
return registrationsCount.Count().ToString();
```

Now i have few questions :

1 ) how can i explore the registered device details ?

2 ) How i can i send a test notification to the ios devices from back end. Below is the code that i am using to send test notifications.

```
 var payload = string.Format(toastTemplate, message);

 hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(payload, "worldnews");
```

3 ) If i am using the web api as back end is it necessary to configure the ios app details    in azure notification hub ? i.e uploading the certificate and other details on azure portal ?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your first problem is how you are calling `GetAllRegistrationsAsync`. The parameter is not the maximum count of registrations you want back. It's the index of the first registration you want. Under most scenarios, that would be 0, not `Int32.MaxValue`

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_GetAllRegistrationsAsync_System_Int32_

```
public Task<CollectionQueryResult<RegistrationDescription>> 
    GetAllRegistrationsAsync(int top)
```

Bear in mind, also, that this method returns a maximum of 100 registrations. If you want more, you'll need to use the ContinuationToken.

Here's the code I use to get the registrations:

```
internal async Task<List<RegistrationDescription>> GetAllRegisteredDevicesAsync()
{
    var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
        Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsMobileAppFullSharedAccessListenerConnection,
        Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsMobileAppHubName,
        Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsTestSendMode);

    var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
    var continuationToken = allRegistrations.ContinuationToken;
    var registrationDescriptionsList = new List<RegistrationDescription>(allRegistrations);
    while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken))
    {
        var otherRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(continuationToken, 0);
        registrationDescriptionsList.AddRange(otherRegistrations);
        continuationToken = otherRegistrations.ContinuationToken;
    }

    return registrationDescriptionsList;
}
```

Note that this method should **only** be used if you have only a few hundred, perhaps a few thousand registrations. If you have tens, hundreds of thousands or millions of registrations, you should not use this method, and find a more efficient method to find what you need.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. That was really heplful :)
There is one more question if you have noticed the 2nd point. I want to send a notification to apple devices. There is a facility on unauthorized notifications for windows phone. is there any way that i can send the same notifications for ios devices without submitting the appkey or certificate ?

Comment: StackOverflow works better if you don't combine questions. But briefly, I don't know any way to send notifications through the Apple Push Notification Service without uploading the certificate you need into Azure. This article shows what to do: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/

Comment: please take a look at this : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-aspnet-register-user-push-notifications/ . Is it still necessary to register the app using certificate and all ? or it can straight be done using the back end web api ?

Comment: It certainly is possible to register devices from the back end, rather than have the devices register themselves. In fact, this is necessary when the back end intends to modify the tags or templates or use native payloads that the apps themselves can't or won't do. However, if you don't need to modify payloads, tags, or templates, then back-end registration is an unnecessary intermediary, since Notification Hubs will manage it all for you. You will still want a secure communication between the apps and your backend, as well.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for the explanation about the "top" parameter. It's really not obvious.

Comment: Why it takes too long if it takes only top 100 records ?

Answer (score 7):

There is one more way if some one just want to retrieve the details of registered devices just for a knowledge not for application purpose. [Service Bus Explorer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a) is available. You can download the project and extract it and run using visual studio.

You will be able to connect to azure services by providing the connection string and owner key. I used this to see the registered devices and sending the test notifications etc. Its a great helpful tool.

Hope this can help some one.

Answer (score 0):

short Code:

```
    private async Task<List<RegistrationDescription>> GetAllRegisteredDevicesAsync()
    {
        List<RegistrationDescription> allRegistrations = new List<RegistrationDescription>();

        var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
            Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsMobileAppFullSharedAccessListenerConnection,
            Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsMobileAppHubName,
            Settings.Default.AzureNotificationsTestSendMode);

        CollectionQueryResult<RegistrationDescription> page = null;
        do
        {
            page = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(page?.ContinuationToken, 0);
            allRegistrations.AddRange(page);
        }
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(page.ContinuationToken));

        return allRegistrations;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.